# Sucking air in to the power steering system from steering rack shaft seals?

Tags: honda, power-steering, steering, power-steering-fluid

Is it possible to suck air in to the power steering system from steering rack shaft seals?

My 2008 Honda Civic is making whining noise and I can see air bubbles in the steering fluid reservoir.

I have replaced the o'ring in suction side. However, I'm still seeing air bubbles (only when turning) and hearing some tapping noise when turning left (drr drr noise from the reservoir like pushing air through the reservoir. like a rattling noise).

Also few drops of fluid also dripping from the right side of the steering rack. I'm assuming when turning left, air is entering to the system from the right side seal.

Is this possible?

Comment: Where is the pump located?  Is it high up on the engine?  Is the reservoir located on the pump or separate to the pump?

Comment: Is this your engine?  Does the video help - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q72M8fUNzXw

Comment: @HandyHowie it is R18A engine. Pump is located at the middle of engine and the reservoir is in a seperate location.

Yep. that's my engine and I already replaced those seals.

Comment: I would have thought that everything after the pump would be under pressure, so air wouldn’t be sucked in.  Therefore I would be looking at the low pressure side of the pump still.

Comment: @HandyHowie I will repair the leak of the rack tomorrow. I found seals. So, we can conclude.

Comment: Let us know how you get on.

Comment: @HandyHowie I replaced 2x seals in main shaft and 1x in pinion. Also I added new oil and the air bubbles went away. I don't know which made it, may be seals or may be new oil?

Comment: You should write an answer to your question.